# How to handle english UK and english US languages with i18next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, i18next

My app is translated in several languages with i18next. Until now, I used only one English translation. But I'd like to have both en-GB and en-US. Truth is, text translations will be the same and the only reason I want both languages is for date formats.

More precisely, I want to pass the good date format to a MUI DatePicker component. Right now, English has MM-DD-YYYY format, unlike most other languages. Obviously, I'd like en-GB to have DD-MM-YYYY format.
Is this rather common use case built in i18next or should I use some kind of hack to avoid having two almost identical translation files to maintain ?

Comment: Using i18next for a date formatting is not common.  Most date packages offer a locale option for formatting which will use host settings to determine that exact case.

Comment: You can use `new Date` and parse it to get the results as per your need.